Generation of arbitrary integer sequences
I want to know that if I consider a positive real number $\theta>0$ and the procedure
$$b_1=\theta$$
$$b_n = \lfloor b_{n-1} \rfloor(b_{n-1}-\lfloor b_{n-1}\rfloor+1)$$
with $a_n:=\lfloor b_n\rfloor$, which nondecreasing integer sequences $\{a_n\}$ can be generated this way (i.e. there exists a $\theta$ that works.) For example, for the Fibonacci sequence $\theta = 2.956938891377988\ldots$ works. This problem was inspired by Project Euler Problem 751.
I know, for example, that $\{2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots\}$ does not work, since we need $2<\theta\leq 3$, but then no $\theta$ works to give us exactly 4.

That technique for generating integer sequence indeed works but only for sequences in which Bertrand's Postulate holds, namely that between $n$ and $2n$ there is at least one number from the sequence.
Two videos from the YT channel Numberphile explain this very well:
Awesome Prime Number Constant (Mills' Constant)
2.920050977316
In the second video James Grimes shows the conditions for this to work and the formula for calculating the integer sequence generating constant.
